# Develop android application with "share-to" functionality

Tags: android, share

I want to develop an android application that receives documents from other apps, converts them to pdf, and sends the pdf to an online API.

My question is: How do I show my app in the list of "share to" applications that are available to most Android Apps? Is there an online tutorial somewhere?

e.g. if you click "share to" on an image, various apps show up (messages, gmail, email, etc) - how do I add my app to this list?

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");

String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";

sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{"abc@def.com,pqr@xyz.com"});
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,URI.parse(filePath));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

I have just copied the code from [Mobile TetPlus](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent/) and added my few statements too. You can read the description there

**Note :** You have to set  your mime type according to the data you want to send/share.

For example

If you want to simply send text then use `plain/text` mime type.

If you want to send audio files then use `audio/mp3` or `audio/3gp` mime type.

If you want to send image files then use `image/jpeg` or `image/png` mime type.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to be able to List your application in that `Dialog`.

which got open when a `Share Intent` is called.

Then `IntentFilter` are your way to go.

Please consider the links here

[What are Intent Filter - StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3321514/593709)

Android Docs

- [Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html)
- [Android Manifest - Intent Filter Element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html)