# How to send broadcast between two activities?

Tags: android, broadcast

I want to send data from one.class to two.class by broadcast,and I need to use DYNAMIC register.
I do not want to use intent.

In my MainActivity:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(action);     

    intent.putExtra("msg", "a");        
    sendBroadcast(intent);  
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,sec.class));
```

In my receiver activity:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(MainActivity.action);

    registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


            tv1.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("msg"));  

        }
          };
```

but tv1 does not show anything

Comment: between classes or activities?

Comment: between two different activities

Comment: use intent filter ,set it on your manifest for your activity

Comment: your code doesnt work, because the broadcast is sent before your second activity is started. Try my solution

Comment: I know the problem,thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try localbroadcast receivers. follow this tutorial, it will help, look to (7. Defining custom events and receivers) on this page
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use intent filter in your manifest and get intent on your Activity

Check this [What are intent-filters in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321514/what-are-intent-filters-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Is it two diferentes activities ? You can use a socket.

Answer (score 0):

You can put Bundles into your startingIntent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("asd",12345);
startActivity(intent);
```

And catch it in NewActivity:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
int value = extras.getInt("asd");
```