# I have created an android app in eclispe. when i install i got two apps installed

Tags: java, android

Friends,

I Have created an android file in eclipse and Exported as an android file. When i install it i got two android files. I have two java files in the app. one is second.java and the other is first.java.

When i install the app in blue stacks , it installed two files . One is first and other is second.
I have a button in my first.java  which goes to the second.java file. How can i solve it by installing only one app in app tray...???
 Here is my code

first.java

```
package com.zacter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class first extends Activity {
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void addListenerOnButton(){
        final Context context=this;
        button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.continuebutton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context,second.class);
                            startActivity(intent);   

            }   
        });


    }

}
```

Second.java
package com.zacter;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class second extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_boostram);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.boostram, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zacter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.zacter.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.zacter.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:parentActivityName="android.app.LauncherActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="android.app.LauncherActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.zacter.Boostram"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_boostram" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: show your manifest...

Comment: yeah its cause of manifest

Comment: Bro .. i have added the manifest file. I am a newbie to android.please tell where to change

Comment: Remove `<intent-filter>` tag from `Boostram`

Comment: <intent-filter> tag must be place on your launcher activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zacter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.zacter.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.zacter.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:parentActivityName="android.app.LauncherActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="android.app.LauncherActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.zacter.Boostram"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_boostram" >

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your manifest files, you are having more than one activities with the intent filter category as launcher.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

The intent category means you are going to have two launcher icons, or two launch points for your application.

You can read more about it here

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/category-element.html

Answer (score 2):

Replace 'LAUNCHER' with 'DEFAULT'

[image]

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321514/what-are-intent-filters-in-android) for further  explaination

Answer (score 0):

Keep this tag in only first activity remove from Boostram activity tag

```
             <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

just Because of these lines.

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

keep this intent filter for only one activity which you want to launch at starting. if you keep category launcher for any other activities it will creates multiple launcher icons in applications. for more details check this link [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/category-element.html)

Answer (score -3):

`<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` will create launcher activity, so if you have multiple LAUNCHER category in AndroidManifest.xml file, multiple launcher activity will generate.

Modify your `AndroidManifest.xml` like below.

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".first"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".second"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >

        </activity>
    </application>
```