# Activity Test Rule fails for activity in androidTest directory

Tags: android, android-testing

I've created a test like so within the androidTest directory

```
public class NoInternetFragmentTests {

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
        FragmentTestActivity.class);

@Test
public void testNoInternet() throws InterruptedException {
```

When i try and run the test I get a can't launch activity error and "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve activity for: Intent"

There is a manifest inside the androidTest directory which looks like so:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.ccc"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <application
        android:name=".application.MyApplication">
        <activity
            android:name=".util.test_activities.FragmentTestActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is inside androidTest and can be seen in the created APK

Any ideas why it is not possible to launch the activity?

Comment: Were you able to get solution to this issue? I am facing the same one.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. At the moment, my "solution" is to put this activity in the main package.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because you are missing itent-filter in your manifest file. You can read more here : [What are intent-filters in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321514/what-are-intent-filters-in-android)

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work unfortunately.  But not sure I should need it. The manifests should just be merged and the main one has a main intent already

Answer (score 0):

I'm using AndroidStudio3.2 & these things helped me:

1.Make sure you have added these dependencies:

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
```

2.Add the annotation : @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Rule
    ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityTestRule=new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }
}
```