# change default start activity error

Tags: android, android-activity

This is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:exported="true" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" />

</application>
```

At the beginning, my project exported property is in the LoginActivity section.
But after I change exported="true" to SplashActivity it's not work...
I tried to change to RegisterActivity section and got the same error. 
Event log is "Error running app: The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter"
my android studio version is 2.3.3 and project min SDK is 19
Is there anyone have the same problem?..

Updare:
This is my latest code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" />
</application>
```

But I got the 
[same problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp1Tf.png)
...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are intent-filters in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321514/what-are-intent-filters-in-android)

Comment: No I just have one...

Answer (score 1):

try defining your Splash activity like this :

```
 <activity
       android:name=".SplashActivity">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Comment: I found only add in the LoginActivity section and will work successfully

Comment: @ChrisWang is you are getting any type of error, then please post that over here

Comment: Only I click the run app button and there is a message "The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter"

Comment: and ADB windows doesn't open

Comment: @ChrisWang make sure app is selected to the left of the top run button in your studio

Comment: and if it still not working then update your question with your latest manifest code.

Answer (score 0):

In the Manifest file you must have an Activity that is set as Main so the app will know what to launch first.

By adding the following intent-filters you set the following Activity as main.

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```